# Flutter Freezed - Union types and "copyWith"

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, freezed, flutter-freezed

I have this union:

```
@freezed
abstract class VeganItem extends VeganItemAbstraction with _$VeganItem {
  @With(GroceryItemMixin)
  const factory VeganItem.groceryItem(
      {int? id,
      String? name,
      String? companyName,
      String? description,
      List<Option>? tags,
      int? rating,
      List<ImagePickerImage>? images}) = GroceryItem;..........
```

There are 4 other subtypes in `VeganItem`.

I have this union type which contains a `VeganItem`:

```
@freezed
abstract class VeganItemEstablishment extends VeganItemEstablishmentAbstraction
    with _$VeganItemEstablishment {
  @With(GroceryItemEstablishmentMixin)
  const factory VeganItemEstablishment.groceryItemEstablishment(
      {int? id,
      Establishment? establishment,
      GroceryItem? veganItem,
      double? price,}) = GroceryItemEstablishment;..............
```

When I make `GroceryItemEstablishment.veganItem` be type `VeganItem`, I can use copywith like this:

```
  mvipVm.entity =
      mvipVm.entity!.copyWith.veganItem!(id: null, images: null);
```

But when I make it be type `GroceryItem`, I have to use copywith like this:

```
  mvipVm.entity = mvipVm.entity!.map(
    groceryItemEstablishment: (value) => value.copyWith(
        veganItem: mvipVm.entity!.veganItem!
            .copyWith(id: null, images: null) as GroceryItem),
    menuItemEstablishment: (value) => value.copyWith(
        veganItem: mvipVm.entity!.veganItem!
            .copyWith(id: null, images: null) as MenuItem),
    restaurantItemEstablishment: (value) => value.copyWith(
        veganItem: mvipVm.entity!.veganItem!
            .copyWith(id: null, images: null) as RestaurantItem),
    eventItemEstablishment: (value) => value.copyWith(
        veganItem: mvipVm.entity!.veganItem!
            .copyWith(id: null, images: null) as EventItem),
    groceryStoreItemEstablishment: (value) => value.copyWith(
        veganItem: mvipVm.entity!.veganItem!
            .copyWith(id: null, images: null) as GroceryStoreItem),
  );
```

The docs mention the field must be on all subtypes to be in `copyWith`. But what about having the same field but with different subtypes?

Is there an alternative solution where I can enter a subtype into the `GroceryItemEstablishment.veganItem` field that gives me a more concise `copyWith` syntax?

EDIT: So far the alternative, keep `veganItem` as the supertype (`VeganItem`), and just type cast it to the subtype (`GroceryItem`) when necessary, is way more manageable.